# neo4j-php-client private and protected fields

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

I am new to neo4j and neo4j-php-clien, and following the tutorial in Basic Usage.

This is what I have:

```
$result = $client->run("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n");

echo var_dump ($result->getRecords());
```

this is the output:

> object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Formatter\RecordView)#31 (3) { ["keys":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "n" } ["values":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Formatter\Type\Node)#40 (3) { ["id":protected]=> int(187) ["labels":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "X2Person" } ["properties":protected]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Ales" ["age"]=> int(34) } } } ["keyToIndexMap":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Formatter\RecordView":private]=> array(1) { ["n"]=> int(0) } }

How can I access the protected and private fields of the record?

Comment: I have already tried 

$record = $result->getRecord();

$record->value('age');

None of the methods except $record->values() works.

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally figured out; I need a reference to the node first.

This works for me:

$query = "MATCH (n:Person) return n";

$result = $client->run($query);

$record=$result->getRecord();

$xNode=$record->get('n');

echo $xNode->value('name')."
";

var_dump($xNode->labels());

....

Comment: Yeah, well it was explained https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client#record-value

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in the documentation : Working with Result Sets, which details completely the next operations

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client#working-with-result-sets